# Triple integral $\iiint 2x$ $dxdydz$ on the region of space defined by $S={x^2 +y^2 + z^2 \le 1 }$

Tags: integration, analysis, spherical-coordinates

I have done the following triple integral $ \displaystyle \iiint 2x ~dx~dy~dz~$
on the region defined by
$S={x^2 +y^2 + z^2 \le 1 }$.

Turning to the spherical coordinates I get

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
x = \rho \cos\theta \sin\phi \\ 
y= \rho\sin\theta \sin\phi \\ 
z = \rho\cos\phi 
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

where $dx~dy~dz = \rho^2\sin\phi  ~d\rho~d\theta~d\phi$ and $\rho \in [0,1], \theta \in [0, 2 \pi], \phi \in [0, \pi] $

The integral therefore becomes

$ \displaystyle 2 \int_0^1 \rho^3 ~d\rho \int_0^{2\pi}\cos\theta~ d\theta \int_0^{\pi}\sin^2 \phi ~d\phi ~$ and the result is $0$.

I'm not sure I did the calculations correctly

Comment: But why $\;0\le\theta\le\frac\pi2\;$ ? The azimuthal angle "sweeps" around the whole plane $\;xy\;$ ...

Comment: Of course the result is zero given the integrand is an odd function of $x$ and there is symmetry about x-plane.

Comment: DonAntonio: I'm sorry I wanted to write [0,2pi]
Math Lover: thank you so much

Comment: I have to take into account the extremes of integration that I put in the integrals .. that is p∈[0,1],θ∈[0,2pi],φ∈[0,pi]

now I correct

Comment: To write correctly $\,pi\;$ do write \pi between dollar signs

Comment: Understood but why do you write _surface_? That would mean integration only over the surface $\rho = 1$. Based on what you say and your integral, it seems you want to integrate over the region $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \leq 1$ which includes the interior of the sphere.

Comment: Oh that's right! I'm sorry.
Integral over a region of space which in this case is the sphere of radius 1

Comment: $\displaystyle = 0$